# Not using Entity Framework for models

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, sharepoint-2010, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm going to try and use MVC4 for an ASP.NET web portal (first time I'll use ASP's MVC), but I don't think the models will be using Entity Framework much.

Perhaps only the `Users` model will, which will contain user profile data, but most of the data presented to the users will either come from `Sharepoint` or `CRM 2011`.

So essentially, my models are going to be Sharepoint items and CRM entities.

I looked at the sample application provided by MVC4 (title `Internet Application` in the templates) and I see that the model uses EF (`AccountModel.cs`).

Is this a requirement as per MVC4's best practices or you can build models from any source you wish and still be within the "best practices" ?

Do you see any obvious "no-no's" of using MVC4 judging by the requirements of the portal application I'll have to build ?

I'm thinking of using some rich content JavaScript library for the UI (Knockout, ExtJS, etc.)

Thanks.

Comment: Entity Framework is an ORM which goes between a database and your application code. You can certainly use any ORM, or no ORM at all, if you so choose - the MVC framework is agnostic in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was built to aid the feature; I don't know if the model is an area to be concerned about best practices.  A model should just contain the data to send to the view.

Note: if you use knockout, your app will do away with server-side models in favor of client-side models in JavaScript; the whole paradigm is different when you shift to the client-side.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. The backend will probably become just an XML/JSON spewing piece of software from my experience, depending on what parameters were sent in the client request.

Comment: If you're just returning JSON/XML in your controllers, then look into ASP.NET Web API, which is build for exactly that.

Comment: Either MVC or Web API would work; Web API was built more specifically for that.  For a client front-end, definitely use JSON as it's easily consumable by JavaScript.

Comment: @BrianMains I'm planning on using ExtJS as library for the UI, which will communicate with the Web API project. In what type of project would you host all the UI portion of the solution? I think it this point, an MVC project is not really helpful as it will hold no `views` so to speak.

Comment: You are right.  You could use MVC or web forms as the shell, but use .html files for the view.  That could allow you to use the server-side for logging in, if you don't want to use client-side authentication.

Answer (score 1):

A model is just a representation of your data that you pass to the view. It can be anything you want, and definitely does not have to come from the Entity Framework.

```
public class MyModel
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class MyController
{
  public ActionResult MyAction
  {
     var account = service.GetCrmEntity("account", myaccountId);

     var myModel = new MyModel();
     myModel.Name = account.name;

     return View(myModel)
  }
}
```